# How should I inject a resource into a Django view?

Tags: django, django-views

I wish to place RPC calls from within the context of a Django view.
This requires the view to have a reference to the client stub.

I understand I could decorate the view as such:

```
@RpcAware
def handle(request, rpc):
  # perform calls on rpc, etc.

def RpcAware(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     return func(*args, get_initialized_rpc(), **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

This feels like it could get in the way of url params.
I realize I could use class-based views and store the resource in the view instance.

Is there a better way to do it though? Could a custom middleware help?

Comment: middleware seems like a good idea to me https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Looks like `inject` had this at one time http://api.python-inject.googlecode.com/hg/html/inject.middleware.DjangoInjectMiddleware-class.html but it's no longer in the current version https://github.com/ivan-korobkov/python-inject